# Google myBuisness data propagation issue with Google Maps, no placeID for buisness profile

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-search, google-my-business-api

I need a placeID, for our business, so I can make api calls.

- Business name: Maler-Teamet.dk
- Address: Engkær 15, 2650 Hvidovre, Danmark
- Address-placeID: ChIJCYGE6K5WUkYRVxTvbfHLWd8

I have a piece of working javascript code, that I'm using to extract reviews of another business, in a test environment, from the Google Places/Maps api, using placeID, and displaying them on a webpage.

After updating our Google myBusiness profile, with the assistance of the Google support, who actually made most of the changes. We, and Google myBusiness, are no longer able to [find the business on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/search/Maler-Teamet.dk/@55.569756,7.9782511,6z/data=!3m1!4b1), and therefore retrieve a placeID.

Using normal [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=maler-teamet.dk), the myBusiness profile never displays either. I'm actually really concerned how this might be affecting seo and rankings.

When including either [Hvidovre](https://www.google.com/search?q=maler-teamet.dk&gws_rd=cr&ei=v3E0V8qpIqSH6ATp3IqoBw#safe=off&q=maler-teamet.dk%20hvidovre) or [Engkær](https://www.google.com/search?q=maler-teamet.dk&gws_rd=cr&ei=v3E0V8qpIqSH6ATp3IqoBw#safe=off&q=maler-teamet.dk%20engk%C3%A6r) in the seach, it does display correctly, and the business profile has a map on it, [that links to the business profile on maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Maler-Teamet.dk/@55.6516379,12.462726,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xc93069008461f508!8m2!3d55.6516379!4d12.462726), which seems to be registered to the city address only, Hvidovre. This doesn't get any results in placeID finder either though. But the profile is there somewhere then.

Using f.ex the [Google placeID finder](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) with our company name, returns no autocomplete, or results. If I use the address registered on our profile, I do get a placeID, but our business is not registered on that placeID, when I make api calls.

With support from Google's myBuisness department, Google has been able to identify that there is an issue, and they have reported the issue on, internally. The reference number for the case is 2-8475000011449.

They have not been able to support the part of the issue related to the Maps/Places Api, or give me a timeline for resolving the issue, since Maps is a different department/branch related to the developers console.

Since technical support through the developers console, apparently requires a premium subscription, I have attempted to contact the sales department, to confirm that I need to pay more than 400$ to report this issue, and create what they call a P1 support case, as I understand it.

Since explaining the issue in a reply, I have actually not heard from them in 4 days now. Despite numerous attempts on my behalf.

Since the only other option Google myBusiness support was able to give was, to report the issue here with the tags google-places-api and google-maps and cross my fingers, I guess I'm hoping the right persons find this.

Comment: I have also reported the issue on google-places-api issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9749&thanks=9749&ts=1463056091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into your issue and was able to find your business place ID. The place ID related to Maler-Teamet.dk is ChIJ91ouygNUUkYRCPVhhABpMMk.

However, as I can see this place has a service area information. Please note that "Service Area Business" results do not appear in Places API. Typically, these businesses don't have an exact location, but rather their service area. That's why they are excluded from the search.

I can suggest keeping in touch with Google My Business team and changing this business to not "Service Area Business".

Comment: It looks like this place is now available via API: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ91ouygNUUkYRCPVhhABpMMk&key=<api_key>](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ91ouygNUUkYRCPVhhABpMMk&key=<api_key>)

Comment: Places API text search also returns results: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Maler-Teamet.dk&key=<api_key>](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Maler-Teamet.dk&key=<api_key>)

Comment: Hi xomena, thank you for taking the time! I did not expect a solution. Using the placeId you have been able to find for us, I'm now able to retrieve the json object and extract and display reivews on our page. I did have to change the business to recieve customers at the adress as you explained, which is inconvenient but acceptable. I was recomended the opposite prior by myBusiness to make it work.  I'm still unable to find the business in placeID finder, or searching on google search or maps, without the use of the adress.

Comment: @xomena did you observe that the place ids of same place is different? and that difference is coming from iOS and Android. 

Have you ever seen this issue? if yes then How would you resolve this issue.